# Regarding icons with "i" in web site

Tags: css, html, icons, glyphicons

I am a beginner in HTML. Till now I have learned about images and how to include them in HTML. I have one sample web project which I am studying. And it has some html code as below

```
   <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                                                    </li>
```

And this code creates a "CROSS" (**X**)image/icon on front end.

Question 1: How the image is actually drawn on front end. Generally to get an image I do something like `"<img src = "image.jpg>"`. So I am confused how that "CROSS" image/icon is getting loaded.

Question 2: Where in the project folder I can find this image/icon. I am not able to find it in the project folder. Is there any special folder where these images/icons are kept.

Question 3: What are the extension of these images. "jpg" "gif" or what?

Question 4: Is there any list of these type of images available online which I can use in the project.

Question 5: If the list is not available online then how can I create images like that and add them using **i** tag.

Please guide me.

Comment: You're seeing Font Awesome code. http://fontawesome.io/ (click on "Examples" for an answer to your main question).

Comment: To add to @Michael_B Font Awesome uses actual font to create them, they are not images.  They are special private-used unicode characters.  Hence why you can adjust their color with css alone.

Comment: Nice. You are right. But I have other questions too. Like how can I find the complete list of icons that are available to me to use Also, can I create icons by myself.? Please guide me.

Comment: You got a link in the first comment, did you check it?

Comment: Thanks @all. I have checked the link and the icons belongs to fontawesome.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer #1

Is a CDN  `content delivery network` is getting the source from the internet I thin what you are using  something like a framework like `fontawesome` here is the link (http://fontawesome.io/icon/times/).

## Answer #2

you can't find the image in any folder because you didn't download it. BUT  you can download the whole package then you will have to link that package to your `HTML` with something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`  In the `<head>` of your `html`, reference the location to your `font-awesome.min.css.` here is the link to instructions (http://fontawesome.io/get-started/)

## Answer #3

they are `svg` files

## Answer 4 & 5

yes there a re bunch of them you can find them all in there just type what are you looking for, you can even animate those icons. (http://fontawesome.io/examples/) examples in the link. just a quick explanation 
    `i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i> fa-3x
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i> fa-4x
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i> fa-5x`
the `class` is used to describe the name of the icon (which icon) 
`fa-2x` is the size of the icon with `fa-5x` been the largest